# Global variable is not changing in python

Tags: python

```
def sells():
    global sold
    sold = 10
    print(sold)
sold = 20
sells()
print(sold)
```

**I added a global statement inside python and assigned the value to 10. Outside of the function I changed the value to 20. But why it still printing 10?**

Comment: you assigned the value THEN executed the function that changed it, you code works perfectly and as it should .

Answer (score 1):

It's because you called the function after you assigned `sold` to 20, so it is now 10.

```py
sells()
sold = 20
print(sold)
```

Comment: No problem! Have fun with Python!

Answer (score 1):

```
Line1:    def sells():
Line2:        global sold
Line3:        sold = 10
Line4:        print(sold)
Line5:    sold = 20
Line6:    sells()
Line7:    print(sold)
```

when execution starts, it will not go inside **sells()** method , first it will assign **sold =20**  as per line no 5. After this you are calling **sells()** method at line no 6, so it will set the variable as global and value to 10 and prints the same. Now after executing **sells()** method it will print sold at line no 7 as per latest value which is 10. Hence it will prints 10 twice.

Comment: Wow. I had never thought it would be so easy. Thanks for explaining in detail dude. May the force be with you